# Performance loss after Java upgrade to Java SE 8 Update 91

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports, java-web-start

We are maintaince legacy Java system (Swing + JasperReports + MSSQL)
After Java automatically update to version 1.8.91 we got lot of troubles.

System critically lost performance.
Most problems we have with `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportFile)`

On previous Java version (Java SE 8 Update 77) middle size reports used 1-10 seconds to compile.
After upgrade to Java SE 8 Update 91 now same report using 30-170 seconds for compilation.

This effect visible better when program start through our local Java web start server.

On Java SE 8 Update 91 it really starting > 10 times slowly

Downgrade to Java SE 8 Update 77 solve problem, but this is problem for us stop upgrade on over than 4000 computers.

How is known how can fix this?

Comment: IMHO, It is better to address this question to the Jaspersoft/Tibco (developers of JasperReports)

Comment: Did you try to use profiler?

Comment: Maybe @TeodorDanciu can help you

Comment: I think problem not in jasper. Whole system has performance loss. Not only report compilation process

Comment: @Rob You can add your comments (posted as answer) here